# Removing value from array in another file?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a file containing this array:

**stafflist.php:**

```
<?php return array (
  2 => '76561198046199189',
  1 => '76561198063610282',
  3 => '76561198042145797',
);?>
```

But I'm trying to remove a value from that array from another file (remove.php)
I've tried everything from making a function that gets the index from the array, to just using `unset(array['id'])` but nothing is working.

Here is my most recent attempt: (inside remove.php)

```
function removeFromArray($steamid, &$array) {
  $index = array_search($steamid, $array);
  if($index !== false) {
     unset($array[$index]);
  }
  return $array;
}

$roster = require dirname(__FILE__)."/../../../stafflist.php";
if(in_array($_GET['steamid'], $roster)) {
  $output = removeFromArray($_GET['steamid'], $roster);
  file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../../stafflist.php", '<?php return ' . var_export($output, true) . ';');
}
```

Sorry if this is a really simple question, I've just been trying for hours on end at this point.

Comment: `$_GET['steamid']` is the values in the array or the keys? Why not just iterate through array and check for if value is equal to `$steamid` and delete it? `foreach ($array as $key => $value) if ($steamid == $value) unset($array[$key]);`

Comment: Just use `array_filter()` on the array: https://3v4l.org/PIWYj You don't actually need a function to do that really simple thing. Also, turn error reporting on and debug by checking the `$roster` to make sure it has what you want, you can write to that file with the server's user, etc.

Comment: You also don't need and should NOT include the closing `?>` PHP tag.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong way to do that, use functions to return the value and  [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to search that key into array:

stafflist.php:

```
<?php 
function getArray(){
return array (
  2 => '76561198046199189',
  1 => '76561198063610282',
  3 => '76561198042145797',
);
}
?>
```

But I'm trying to remove a value from that array from another file (remove.php) I've tried everything from making a function that gets the index from the array, to just using unset(array['id']) but nothing is working.

Here is my most recent attempt: (inside remove.php)

```
include_once "/../../../stafflist.php";
function removeFromArray($steamid, &$array) {
  $index = array_search($steamid, $array);
  if($index) {
     unset($array[$index]);
  }
 //you don't need the return because you already referenced the argument as a reference to the array sended by the user, so all your interactions inside this function will go to main array as well
}

$roster = getArray();
if(in_array($_GET['steamid'], $roster)) {
  removeFromArray($_GET['steamid'], $roster);
  file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__)., '<?php return ' . var_export($roster, true) . ';');
}
```

Comment: Why is a function better here than returning from the file?

Comment: If the file is an ini file or something like that, it's okay. In the worst case, only the array loaded in a variable it's okay too. But put return in an array and do file_get_contents it's crazy for me, seriously.

Comment: It's perfectly fine. That's how `var_export()` is supposed to work. Wrapping a function around it simply adds unnecessary complexity (you have to then call the function). It doesn't hurt, but it's not needed and won't solve the OP's problem (I imagine).

Comment: No, it's unnecessary, it's a minimum concept of encapsulation for me, like get in a class.

Comment: I know it looks weird, but there's no encapsulation needed, because in this case it's not assigned until the var returned from `require` is set; this simply makes `include` and `require` act like little function wrappers for you.